# Onchange Handler not response for this.setState({userName:event.target.value}) Username:Undefined , Password:Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

***After Pressing SignIn button, Alert should appear as Username: "Entered Value" and Password: "Enter Value".But now it shows Username: Undefined, Password: Undefined.
How Can I fix this.***

```
export default class Login extends Component{
    
    state={userName:"",password:""}

    setUName=(event)=>{
        this.setState({userName:event.target.value})
    }

    setPW=(event)=>{
        this.setState({password:event.target.value})
    }

    onSubmit=(event)=>{
        event.preventDefault()
        const {userName,password}=this.state;
        alert(`Username:${userName},Password:${password}`);
    }
    render(){
        
        return (
            <ImageBackground source={require('../../src/login.png')} style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.header}>
                        Welcome
                    </Text>
                </View>
        
                <View>
                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <TextInput style={styles.txtInput}
                            placeholder='Username'
                            returnKeyType='next'
                            onChange={this.setUName}
                        />
        
                        <TextInput style={styles.txtInput}
                            placeholder='Password'
                            returnKeyType='next'
                            secureTextEntry
                            onChange={this.setPW} 
                        />
                       
                    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

In react-native, you can get value from onChangeText prop from TextInput component.

Try this

```
      setUName=(value)=>{
        this.setState({userName:value})
    }


<TextInput style={styles.txtInput}
                            placeholder='Username'
                            returnKeyType='next'
                            onChangeText={this.setUName}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass function on OnChange replace your onchange property with

```
  <TextInput style={styles.txtInput}
   placeholder='Username'
   returnKeyType='next'
   onChangeText={userName=> this.setState({ userName})}
   />
```

Comment: if this answer is useful for you so please upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using TextInput, this may be custom created or from some styling library. You should log the argument once and check, where exactly the value is coming, so try the below code and check in console and you will know what to do next.

```
setUName=()=>{
    console.log(arguments)
}
```

Its always the best debugging practice to `console.log(arguments)` as in some library, these events are customEvents and values are in 2nd or 3rd argument.

Comment: Thanks for instructions